# Best reference books for beginners

Tags: book-recommendation

Which are the best reference books I can use for mathematics which includes both good theory and numericals? Im a beginner so plz suggest good books.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, editing the question, after a comment/answer has been made, in a way to reflect completely different information, is not generally considered to be a good practice.

Comment: What level, what area of mathematics?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Algebra and mathematical analysis, undergraduate level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend "Principle of Mathematical Analysis" by Walter Rudin.

Once you get through the basic concepts then you can use any reference book you want. Even Wikipedia would help.

Comment: Please don't use Wikipedia as a textbook, that's a terrible idea.

Comment: @Wood I meant for quick reference. I personally felt Wiki is always faster to quickly brush up some formulas.